# Which functions satisfy the following condition on discrete Fourier coefficients?

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, fourier-analysis

**Background**
I am studying a numerical method for solving 2D heat transfer problem (a splitting scheme in time combined with certain space approximation using FEM with rectangular meshes).
On the uniform mesh (as a certain simplified case) using the derived eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the arising discrete operators, the following condition was obtained as necessary for convergence:

**Statement**
Consider a function $T^0(x,y)$ (the initial temperature) which can be decomposed after projecting to the uniform mesh with nodes $(x_i, y_j)$ as:
$$
T^0(x_i,y_j) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{j=1}^{N} T_{ij} \, u_i(k) \, u_j(l)
$$
where $u_i, u_j$ are ``discrete harmonics'' (eigenvectors)
$$
u_i(k) = sin \frac{\pi i(2k-1)}{2N}, i, k = 1, ... N. 
$$ and $T_{ij}$ - decomposition coefficients.

Then for convergence of the method we need the following sum to be bounded uniformly w.r.t mesh step $h$:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{j=1}^{N} T^2_{ij} \lambda_j^2 (\lambda_i + \lambda_j)^3  \leq C < \infty
$$
with $C$ independent from $h$ and $N$.

Here $h = 1/N \rightarrow 0$, $\lambda_k \sim \frac{\gamma_k}{h^2}$, $\gamma_k = 2 sin \frac{\pi k h}{2}$, $k = 1, ..., N$.

My **question** is whether the condition above (or any similar) is known in the literature and/or there are any results related to the class of functions which satisfy this condition?

The simplified version of the condition (taking $\gamma^k \sim \pi k h$, $h \rightarrow 0$) reads as follows:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{j=1}^{N} T^2_{ij} j^4 (i^2 + j^2)^3 \leq C < \infty
$$
with $C$ independent from $h$ and $N$.

Any remarks and comments are welcome.

Comment: if $f(x,y) = \sum_{n,m} c_{n,m} e^{2i \pi (nx+my)}$ then $\sum_{n,m} c_{n,m} (2i\pi m)^2 (2i \pi m-2\pi n)^3 e^{2i \pi (nx+my)} = \partial_y(\partial_y-i \partial_x)^3 f(x,y)$ and $\|\partial_y(\partial_y-i \partial_x)^3f\|_{L^2([0,1]^2)} = \int_0^1\int_0^1 |\partial_y(\partial_y-i \partial_x)^3 f(x,y)|^2dxdy = (2\pi)^{8} \sum_n c_{n,m} m^4 (n^2+m^2)^3$. With a sine basis it is the same for odd functions.So your condition is $\partial_y^{1+k} \partial_x^{3-k} f \in L^2(\mathbb{T_2})$